# How to load a CSS file into WordPress admin area using Child Theme?

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme

I want to load a css file into **Wordpress Dashboard** using child theme?

Comment: Please, read [ask]. Then file an [edit].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook to load CSS in admin area.

This goes in your themes `functions.php`. Assumed that your file is at `child_theme_path/css/admin-css.css`

```
function wpse239532_load_admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-css.css', false, '1.0.0' );
   }

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse239532_load_admin_style' );
```